# I see that my code does not follow after "socket socket = serverSocket.accept();", program gets stuck here

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

Image :

[Please view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkKlX.jpg)

I am trying to do socket programming in android emulators , running client and server on two different emulators. I see that my code does not follow after "socket socket = serverSocket.accept();", program gets stuck here.
i am using ip : 10.0.2.2 as the other ip's give I/O exception.
Also, i know what serverSocket.accept() does,  my problem is that i am not able to fix the issue. Why is it waiting for client always even though my client is trying to connect to it. Please review my server and client code and et me know if anyone can figure out the issue.

Server :

```
package com.example.serverside;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView info, infoip, msg;
    String message = "";
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

        infoip.setText(getIpAddress());

        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                                + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
                    }
                });

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;
                    message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                            + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            msg.setText(message);
                        }
                    });

                    SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
                            socket, count);
                    socketServerReplyThread.run();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        int cnt;

        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            cnt = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + cnt;

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.close();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }

        return ip;
    }
}
```

Client :

```
package com.example.clientside;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }});
    }

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
            new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                            editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
                            Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()));
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }};

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                /*
                 * notice:
                 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
                 */
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }finally{
                if(socket != null){
                 try {
                        socket.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `i am using ip : 10.0.2.2 ` Where are you using that? It would be a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting stuck actually... when your client get connected then further code will execute

on Server code get Ip address from this code

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();

                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

when you get ip address then try to connect with this ip and port 8080

Comment: I am taking ip and port from user at run time from the app, after that when the user clicks on "connect" from client app, the socket inputstream return -1. which i guess is because the server is still waiting for connection. Can you please elaborate a bit on what to modify.

Comment: check this example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android some screenshots also given in this example

Comment: I have added a screenshot at the top of post, please check.

Comment: on client app add 192.168.200.2 ip address

Comment: make sure you have internet permission registered in manifest

Comment: make sure your both phone connected to same network because one ip is 192.168.200 and another is192.168.232

Comment: `public static String getLocalIpAddress()` You should not only call this function on the server but also on the client. Here all emulaters have the same local ip to begin with. It makes no sense trying to connect then.

Comment: `I am taking ip and port from user at run time from the app` Can be. But how would we know what the user types in? And .. how would the user know what to type in? Please specify ip's.

Comment: @blackapps so when the server app runs, the ips show on the ui, u can check the screenshot. and client enters one of those ip's on its ui console on client app

Comment: @GaneshPokale i tried with both the ip's you have mentioned but its not working.

Comment: Why would the server display more than one ip? I dont get it. But please try getLocalIpAddress() on both server and client emulator and report. Or execute  getIpAddress() on the client side too. Is there any difference with the server side?